# nth child for second last doesn't work in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and I do below lines, the first one is ok but second is not. What I want is to remove the last and the second last td.

```
$('.table td:last-child').remove()
$('.table td:nth-child(1)').remove()
```

Comment: Try once by changing the sequence

Comment: Use [`:gt`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) `$(".table td:gt(-3)").remove();`. Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/Lbkzfueg/)

Comment: @Tushar Consider the difference between this and an answer using last-child:  https://jsfiddle.net/Lbkzfueg/3/

Answer (score 3):

After removing the last-child, the second last becomes the last-child.
Just write

```
$('.table td:last-child').remove()
$('.table td:last-child').remove()
```

Comment: @Tushar, She explained that - once the last td is removed from the DOM, using the same selector again will now select what was originally the second-to-last td.

Comment: Not needed, use `:gt`. Check my comment on question.

Comment: @Tushar This may be equivalent in some situations, but they are not the same in all situations.  last-child/nth-child are counted only within their parent element.  `:gt` is across all matched elements.  In a table with multiple rows, `:gt` would only remove the last 2 whereas this answer would delete the last two in each row.

Answer (score 1):

One statement alternative

```
$('.table td:last-child, .table td:nth-last-child(2)').remove()
```

`:nth-last-child` counts from the last element, so `:nth-last-chld(2)` is the second last

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
$(".table td:nth-last-child(-n+2)").remove();
```

```js
$(function(){
    $(".table td:nth-last-child(-n+2)").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>TD #0</td>
        <td>TD #1</td>
        <td>TD #2</td>
        <td>TD #3</td>
        <td>TD #4</td>
        <td>TD #5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TD #1</td>
        <td>TD #2</td>
        <td>TD #3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TD #1</td>
        <td>TD #2</td>
        <td>TD #3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```